# SQL Server & VB.Net issues with stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- Visual Studio 2010

I have 2 tables: first table is `Countries` which has 3 columns `country-id, countryname, cityname`.

I am displaying country name and city name for my dropdownlist in Visual Studio.

My second table name userselection columns are `id, country-id, username, date`

I then created a form on Visual Studio that has a button to send information to SQL Server through a stored procedure.

My stored procedure so far is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Proc [dbo].[usp_userinput]
    (@country-id int,
     @username(75),
     @date datetime)
AS
    INSERT INTO [CustomApplications].[dbo].userselection ([country-id], [username], [date])
    VALUES (@country-Id, @username, @date)
```

However when I send it says too many arguments and I think that is because it is trying to send the countryname and the cityname rather than just the country-id. Any help on how i would create a stored procedure to just send the country-id and still have the values that populate the dropdownlist be the countryname, cityname.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the - symbol from your variable name.  SQL Server thinks you are trying to do math.  You also need to put the data type for your @username variable.

```
USE [CountryApplications]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_userinput]  
 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Proc [dbo].[usp_userinput]
(@countryid int,
 @username varchar(75),
 @date datetime)

As

INSERT INTO [CustomApplications].[dbo].userselection
([country-id],
[username],
[date])

Values 
(@countryId,
@username,
@date)
```

Comment: im sorry I had the datatype just forgot to type it. I tried you what you said and it still says too many arguments. Not sure if you were just correcting my procedure or answering the question but tried what you said any how and still does not work.

Comment: okay maybe an easier example to understand. If there is two tables movies with values of(movieid, moviename, movierating) then a renters table with values of (id,rentername,renterdate,movieid) basically what i need to know in my storeprocedure is how do i get the movieid to pass over to the renters table. wihtout passing the moviename and movierating just want the movieid to pass over.